# Excel.Range.Text value still reading as '######' even after doing an AutoFit() on column

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I need to read in the formatted values of some excel data (a mixture of dates, numbers and text that I will not know format of prior to runtime) as a series of rows, discarding all blank cells.

I do an autofit on the input columns, so in theory the columns are now wide enough the displayed values of those cells should not be ####, but the autofit seems to have no effect on my output data.

```
int rowCount = allCells.Rows.Count;
int colCount = allCells.Columns.Count;
List<List<string>> nonBlankValues = new List<List<string>>();


//to stop values coming out as series of #### due to column width, resize columns
foreach (Excel.Range col in allCells.Columns)
{
    col.AutoFit();
}
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    List<string> row = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
    {
        Excel.Range cellVal = (Excel.Range)allCells.Cells[i + 1, j + 1]; //Excel ranges are 1 indexed not 0 indexed
        string cellText = cellVal.Text.ToString();
        if (cellText != "")
        {
            row.Add(cellText);
        }

    }
    if (row.Count > 0)
    {
        nonBlankValues.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the format to 'General' or something like that. Don't know the exact code for you application but it should be something like:

```
Range.NumberFormat = "General";
```

This worked for me, I got rid of  the ### (Has something to do with the maximum amount of charactes in a cell). (I used 'Standaard' because my version is Dutch). So I suppose it's 'General' in  the English versions. Range is in my case:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
```

Comment: This does the same thing as replacing `Cell.Text` with `Cell.Value`  It gets me past the problem of extracting ###, however it also overrides the formatting of dates (setting them back to the number value). And I cannot just use the datetime fromOA... conversion method because I don't know which columns are which datatype (format changes at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Manually resizing the columns seems to fix the problem therefore...

Seems like making my own AutoFit equivalent is the only way to go :( so I have 2 options...

A. Faster way is to add a fixed amount to every column before the data read, and then remove it afterward

```
    foreach (Excel.Range col in allCells.Columns)
    {
        col.ColumnWidth = (double)col.ColumnWidth + colWidthIncrease;
    }
```

...loop from question here...

```
    foreach (Excel.Range col in allCells.Columns)
    {
        col.ColumnWidth = (double)col.ColumnWidth - colWidthIncrease;
    }
```

B. Have a feedback loop that when I encounter an entry of only #, iteratively increase by a fixed amount until this changes (with a loop counter check to terminate)

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    List<string> row = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
    {
        string cellText="";
        int maxLoops = 10;
        int loop = 0;
        bool successfulRead = false;
        while (!successfulRead && loop < maxLoops)
        {
            Excel.Range cellVal = (Excel.Range)allCells.Cells[i + 1, j + 1]; //Excel ranges are 1 indexed not 0 indexed
            cellText = cellVal.Text.ToString();
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(cellText, @"#+"))
            {
                successfulRead = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cellVal.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = Math.Min((double)cellVal.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth + 5, 255);
            }
            loop++;
        }
        if (cellText != "")
        {
            row.Add(cellText);
        }

    }
    if (row.Count > 0)
    {
        nonBlankValues.Add(row);
    }
}
```